# How to incorporate index in R lapply statements

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I'm trying to rewrite a loop as an lapply statement, but I am getting stuck because I cannot figure out how to incorporate the index within the function.  I recently asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158554/alternatives-to-a-for-loop-with-indexing-r) on SO and received an elegant response, but the response doesn't generalize to this problem.

I'm working with a set of records, and the records are structured in a long format.  I can identify each unique set of records by a unique string.  The rows that I want to fix always occurs exactly two rows after these unique strings.

Here is the reproducible data:

```
text <- c("_____", "A: aaa", "bbb", "C: cccc", "D: dddd",
    "_____", "A: aaa:aaa", "bbb", "C: ccc", "D: dddd", "E: eeee",
    "_____", "A: aaa", "bbb:bbb", "C: ccc", "D: dddd")
```

And here is the loop that does what I need it to do.  It works just fine on a very small data set, but I have to apply this logic in a few different ways to a few hundred thousand rows of data -- a more efficient method is definitely needed!

```
for(i in 3:length(text)){
    text[i] <- ifelse(grepl("\\_{5}", text[i-2]) == TRUE,
    paste("B: ", text[i], sep=""), text[i])
    text
    }
```

Of course, feel free to redirect if there are existing problems on SO that I did not identify.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't look more into the problem.  But you could get the expected result by `indx <- which(grepl('_{5}', text)); text[indx+2] <- paste0('B: ', text[indx+2])`

Comment: Ahhhh ... that makes sense!  I certainly could do that.  I'm still curious as to incorporating an index in `lapply` for learning purposes.

Comment: If you want to do the same thing in `sapply` using the `indx`, perhaps `text[indx+2] <- sapply(indx, function(x) paste0('B: ', text[x+2]))` (which is kind of unnecessary)

Comment: @akrun Your first comment was perfect.  Your second comment clarifies what I was trying to understand to better understand the apply functions.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich  For somebody expert in R, the redirect to the duplicate may seem immediately generalizable.  Not exactly sure how the post solves the question I asked.

Comment: It shows you several different ways you can access the list index in the `lapply` call.  Make the body of your for loop a function and call it from `lapply`.  If you just want your code to be faster, put your for loop in a function, compile it (via the compiler package), and it will likely be faster than `lapply`. It will be faster yet if you change the entire for loop body to only `if(grepl("_____",text[i-2],fixed=TRUE)[1L]) text[i] <- paste0("B: ", text[i])`.

Answer (score 2):

To incorporate index into `lapply`, do this:

```
lapply(1:length(text), function(i) doStuff(text[i]) )
```

Comment: This just feels wrong. It might run ok but I don't think it's good practice to access objects in the global environment while inside a function. Here, the `doStuff` function is accessing the `text` variable directly from the workspace. So many nasty things can happen that way.